# how do I make a function wait until the variable 'rows' contains the result of a mysql query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, function, mysql2

The client.mysqllocal function is supposed to return rows.

My current code: https://pastebin.com/hgt2DwSY

```
 const mysql = require('mysql2');
    
    let pool  = mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit : 10,
      host            : 'localhost',
      user            : 'user',
      password        : 'passwd',
      database        : 'database',
      waitForConnections: true,
      queueLimit: 0
    });
    
    client.mysqllocal = async function localmysql(mySQL_db, mySQL_query){
      let rows;
         pool.getConnection(async function(err, conn) {
            
          if (err){ 
            console.log(err);  
          }
    
        conn.changeUser({database : mySQL_db}, function(err) {
          if (err){ 
            console.log(err);
          } 
        });
    
          conn.query(mySQL_query), function (error, results, fields) {
            rows = results
          }
        conn.release()
      })
      return rows;
    }
    
    let func = client.mysqllocal('database','SELECT * FROM `guild_config` WHERE `guild_id` = "guildid"');
    console.log(func);
```

P.S. this is a code snippet, I have a client defined above :) .

Answer (score 0):

In this instance I would probably promisify your querying function

```js
 const mysql = require('mysql2');
    
    let pool  = mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit : 10,
      host            : 'localhost',
      user            : 'user',
      password        : 'passwd',
      database        : 'database',
      waitForConnections: true,
      queueLimit: 0
    });
    
    client.mysqllocal = function localmysql(mySQL_db, mySQL_query) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let rows;
           pool.getConnection(async function(err, conn) {

            if (err){ 
              reject(err);  
            }

          conn.changeUser({database : mySQL_db}, function(err) {
            if (err){ 
              reject(err);
            } 
          });

            conn.query(mySQL_query), function (error, results, fields) {
              rows = results
            }
          conn.release()
        })
        resolve(rows);
      });
    }
    
    client.mysqllocal('database','SELECT * FROM `guild_config` WHERE `guild_id` = "guildid"').then(func => console.log(func));
```

Comment: Just don't forget to `await` the call to client.mysqllocal() ;)

Comment: @ScottyJamison
I did something like this, but the console does not return any errors or results, it is empty.

Code: https://pastebin.com/g0CmYGKb

Comment: On the `conn.query(mySQL_query), function (error, results, fields)` line, I see you're just ignoring that error variable. Try doing a reject() on that error if it has a value, and see if that causes any helpful error messages to show up. e.g. `if (error) reject(error)`

Comment: Sorry I missed that error when I was converting it :/

Answer (score 0):

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

let pool  = mysql.createPool({ 
   connectionLimit : 10,
   host            : 'localhost',
   user            : 'user',
   password        : 'passwd',
   database        : 'database'
});

client.getLocal = (db, query, callback) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, con) => {
        if(err) reject(err);

        con.changeUser({
            database: db
        }, (err) => { if(err) reject(err) });

        con.query(query, (error, result, fields) => {
            return callback(result);
        })
    })
}

client.getLocal('dbname', 'query', (result) => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

What I did here was specify a function *inside* a function so that I can play with the data that the query gives me, and doesn't require async either! Promises are much more preferred but I consider my callbacks to be a bit more flexible, and beginners are prone to confusion when using promises, just like I was! I'd say use a promise as the question above me does.